# Mocking method in mockito returns a Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm writing a test that calls a method from another service:

```
  // Setup mocks
  private GoalService goalService;
  private Principal principal;
  private Goal goal;
  private SecurityService securityService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    goalService = new GoalService();
    principal = mock(Principal.class);
    goal = mock(Goal.class);
    securityService = mock(SecurityService.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRequesterOwnsGoalIsTrue() {
    doReturn(1).when(securityService).getUserIdByPrincipal(principal);
    when(goal.getUsersUserId()).thenReturn(1);
    boolean userOwnsGoal = goalService.requesterOwnsGoal(principal, goal);
    assertEquals(true, userOwnsGoal);
  }
```

During debug, when I call `securityService.getUserIdByPrincipal(principal)` I get a NPE. I am not sure why. Ideally, what I want is for the method call to return 1, I don't care about testing *those* function internal in this unit test.

### Actual Code

```
  Boolean requesterOwnsGoal(Principal principal, Goal goal) {
    Optional<Goal> optionalGoal = Optional.ofNullable(goal);
    if (optionalGoal.isPresent()) {
      return secService.getUserIdByPrincipal(principal) == optionalGoal.get().getUsersUserId();
    }
    throw new StandardUserException("Requesting user does not have access to goal");
  }
```

Stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.habicus.core.service.Goal.GoalService.requesterOwnsGoal(GoalService.java:170)
    at com.habicus.core.service.Goal.GoalServiceTest.testRequesterOwnsGoalIsTrue(GoalServiceTest.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you are showing does not *call* that method. It only creates a "invocation specification".

Comment: You need to add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: @GhostCat What else does there need to be? The internals of the securityService method don't matter as I'm wanting it to be mocked entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `doReturn(1).when(securityService).getUserIdByPrincipal(any(principal));` to make it work.

Or

`doReturn(1).when(securityService).getUserIdByPrincipal(any(Principal.class));`

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work. I had to add @InjectMocks to the service instantiation. However, this works when I add that annotation. Is this necessary?

Comment: This is because, principal object is decided at runtime and you're Mocking is done before it is ran, so we need to tell Mockito that any type of "principal" can be in my mocked method.

Comment: Another solution would be to pass Exact Principal object (with values) which will be passed as actual argument during the method invocation. But this is something which you cannot pre-define, it will change per unit test cases, and that's why you're mocking "Principal" object. 

But now when you mock it, when that function is called in reality then the principal object passed is different than you specified (you specified mock principal), that's why it fails as it doesn't have any corresponding mocking statement (when.then), so you need to do `any()`.

Comment: It worked only when I added injectmocks and didn't initialize the object in the setup function.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown so far indicates that you are in fact creating a mock object. But you are not *injecting* that mock into your class under test!

Just creating mocks isn't sufficient. You have to ensure that they get used by the code you are testing!

Most likely that is your problem here, but as we still don't have a [mcve] we can't be sure.

Comment: I think you're right, I added the @InjectMocks annotation and it seems to have fixed it. I'm not sure what else I would need to add to answer this question sufficiently?

Comment: Also, it fails when I instantiate the GoalService class in the @Before annotation

Comment: @RyanS Sorry, but this is **not at all** how SO works. The very first comment I gave you was to provide a [mcve] - an example that we can use to **repro** your problem. Instead of doing that, you keep coming back with a piece of code here, and a comment there. Again: this is not how anybody can reasonably help you. And beyond that your comments, sorry, imply that you have *no* idea what you are doing. You can't use mockito by **not** knowing how it works. You should rather step back and read some good tutorials (esp given the fact that you combine it with spring) **first**.

Comment: @RyanS Instead of putting down "random" content hoping that it achieves what you need. That is **not** how you program. You *first* spend the time required to learn the tools you intend to use. And finally: I took the time to give input to you repeatedly. You keep coming back with more questions, but at the same time, you are not even willing to show any form of appreciation?